# Adding all ID's in an array from MongoDB with Java

Tags: java, mongodb

I wanted to add all of the ID's inside of MongoDB to an array with using Java. How do I take ID's or any data form and put in an array from JAVA?

PS: I'm newbie with nosql database structure and I'm using MongoDb 3.2

Code is so far something like this.

```
public void ArrayEx(){

    MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost",27017);
    MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("dbTest");
    MongoCollection<Document> collection =database.getCollection("colTest");
    MongoCursor<Document> cursor = collection.find().iterator();
    while(cursor.hasNext()) {

      //What should I add here?

    }
}
```

Comment: You want to have a `long[]` of `_id` ?

Comment: I want to reach every _id put them in array so that I can create a combobox of it.

Comment: You can try `MongoCursor<Document> cursor = collection.find().projection(new Document("_id", 1)).iterator();
        while(cursor.hasNext()) {
            Document result = cursor.next();
            Long id = result.getLong("_id");
            // add to combobox
        }`

Answer (score 1):

If you want only the ids, you can use the mongodb distinct function

```
List Ids = collection.distinct("_id");
```

Comment: I wanted to put them in array one by one so that I can create a combobox automatically.

Comment: I got the Idea from your answer, but I have to write some more code ;-)

List<ObjectId> ids = StreamSupport.stream(collection.distinct("_id", ObjectId.class).spliterator(), false).collect(Collectors.toList());

Answer (score 0):

Modify your method as follows :

```
public void ArrayEx() {

    MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
    MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("dbTest");
    MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("colTest");
    MongoCursor<Document> cursor = collection.find().iterator();

    ArrayList<String> listOfIDS = new ArrayList<>();
    while (cursor.hasNext()) {
        listOfIDS.add(cursor.next().getObjectId("_id").toString());
    }

    String ids[] = new String[listOfIDS.size()];
    ids = listOfIDS.toArray(ids);
}
```

Comment: Here's the thing, I'm using String, when I try to do with your example it says String cannot be converted to Long, after that when I change your codes with String this time it says Object cannot be converted to String, so what should I do?

Comment: On which line it says `String cannot be converted to Long` ?

Comment: It says on the localhost, I'm not sure in which line but probably problem occurs in here " listOfIDS.add(cursor.next().getLong("_id")); " because when I change here to String that case it says ObjectId cannot be cast to String.

Comment: Are you using MongoDB's default `_id` or you have overridden the `_id` to be `long`? I mean are you sure your `_id` field is `long`?

Comment: My _id field should be String, then again I cannot use String too because It says ObjectId cannot be cast to String...

Comment: It's now giving the error " java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.bson.types.ObjectId " what have I got myself in to.

Comment: It looks like you mixed id types some are strings and some are objectids